# rails model default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my model migration

```
class CreateSwimmingClassschedules < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :swimming_classschedules do |t|
      t.integer :slot_id
      t.integer :coach_id
      t.integer :level_id , :default => 1
      t.string :note

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I expect after I call

```
Swimming::Classchedule.create(:coach_id=>8)
```

It will generate a default level_id in table. But somehow it didn't work. I'm in the dev environment using SQLite.

I added

```
 :default => 1
```

after I ran

```
rake db:migrate
```

Does it matter?
Something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding that line after you have run your migrations will not make the change.

Your syntax is correct but you will need to run a migration with that addition. Consider making a separate migration file like this:

```
class ChangeLevelId < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :swimming_classschedules, :level_id, :integer, :default => 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you added `:default => 1` AFTER you did a `rake db:migrate`, you will need to do a `rake db:rollback` and do a remigration of your database.   That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Is it `Classchedule` or `Classschedule` ?

When I have a problem with my database, I recreate it :

```rb
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```